How to get every value associated with another value as with family members?
I think I've almost figured out a solution using the array_agg function in Snowflake SQL, but I'm stuck on the last part.
So for example, say that family instances have a UID like family_id, but I want to merge all members that were ever related to one another into a single array.
Here's the base table:



family_id
member_id




abc
111222


abc
333444


xyz
111222


xyz
555666


def
777888


def
999000



I've been able to get this:



family_id
member_list




abc
111222,333444


xyz
111222,555666


def
777888,999000



but my desired output is this:



member_list




111222,333444,555666


777888,999000



Here's my query so far:
with family1 as (
    select 111222 as member_id, 'abc' as family_id union
    select 333444 as member_id, 'abc' as family_id union
    select 111222 as member_id, 'xyz' as family_id union
    select 555666 as member_id, 'xyz' as family_id union
    select 777888 as member_id, 'def' as family_id union
    select 999000 as member_id, 'def' as family_id
)

select
   family_id
   ,array_to_string(array_agg(member_id) within group (order by member_id asc), ',') as member_list
from family1
group by family_id

Any ideas on how I can get my desired output?

I think in the member_list  in first row you want 111222,333444, 555666  instead of 111222,333444,777888  since 555666 is related to xyz ?

I have added answer to match 111222,333444, 555666 as per my understanding, do let me know

Steps

CTE member_connections : member connections will identify members within the same family.

CTE initial_connections : All members within same family are connected in this

CTE recursive_groups : Propagate connections until all members are assigned to a group (this step mimics a graph traversal)

CTE final_groups : This ensures all members are assigned to the same group, preventing duplicates

CTE aggregated_members : Aggregate members by their group and generate the final list
   WITH family1 AS (     
    SELECT 111222 as member_id, 'abc' as family_id union
    SELECT 333444 as member_id, 'abc' as family_id union
    SELECT 111222 as member_id, 'xyz' as family_id union
    SELECT 555666 as member_id, 'xyz' as family_id union
    SELECT 777888 as member_id, 'def' as family_id union
    SELECT 999000 as member_id, 'def' as family_id
),
member_connections AS (
    SELECT f1.member_id AS member_id_1, f2.member_id AS member_id_2
    FROM family1 f1
    JOIN family1 f2 
        ON f1.family_id = f2.family_id 
        AND f1.member_id != f2.member_id
),
initial_connections AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT member_id_1 AS member_id, member_id_1 AS group_id
    FROM member_connections
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT member_id_2 AS member_id, member_id_1 AS group_id
    FROM member_connections
),
recursive_groups AS (
    SELECT member_id, group_id
    FROM initial_connections
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.member_id, g.group_id
    FROM recursive_groups g
    JOIN initial_connections c
        ON g.group_id = c.member_id
    WHERE g.member_id != c.member_id
),


final_groups AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT member_id, MIN(group_id) AS group_id
    FROM recursive_groups
    GROUP BY member_id
),
aggregated_members AS (
    SELECT group_id, array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT member_id) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY member_id), ',') AS member_list
    FROM final_groups
    GROUP BY group_id
)

SELECT member_list
FROM aggregated_members
ORDER BY group_id;





Incredible! You are a genius! Thank you so much!!!

Thank you so much! and really glad it it worked for you, if you found it helpful, you could accept as answer :)
